# Перезагрузка страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать разовую перезагрузку страницы. 
Я сделала вот так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var reload = sessionStorage.getItem('reload');
    if(!reload){
        sessionStorage.setItem('reload', 1);
        window.location.reload();
    } 
});
```

Но страница все равно не перезагружается. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2):

Что такое

> Разовая перезагрузка страницы

?

Текущий алгоритм перезагружает страницу именно только один раз. При первом посещении в текущей сессии браузера. Затем Вы устанавливаете параметр `reload` и страница перестает запускаться. Вам нужно определить в какой момент страницу нужно опять перезапустить и тогда сбросить параметр `reload`.

Вот такой код будет перезагружать страницу при каждом нечетном посещении

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var reload = sessionStorage.getItem('reload');
    if(!reload){
        sessionStorage.setItem('reload', 1);
        window.location.reload();
    } else
      sessionStorage.setItem('reload', null);
});
```

Comment: "только один раз. При первом посещении" - из текущей сессии браузера.

Comment: Разовая перезагрузка - имею в виду, что один раз при текущей сессии. В случае, если человек очистил историю, разовая перезагрузка происходит снова. 
То есть мой алгоритм почему-то не перезагружает страницу, в случае, если история очищена.

Comment: @Kira Очистка истории подразумевает очистку сессий? Мне кажется, что нет. Сессии очищаются при перезапуске браузера. Может Вам нужно использовать `localStorage`?

Comment: @Kira э-э-э, а почему Вы решили, что очищение истории без закрытия браузера начинает новую сессию?

Comment: @Igor Спасибо за уточнение. Подправил ответ

Comment: @AntonShchyrov прошу прощения, я имела в виду очистку кэша. 
Но даже если я перезагружаю браузер, мой алгоритм не работает.

Comment: @Igor потому что я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в данных терминах. Прошу прощения.